# Why is .pyc file created sometimes in same directory and sometimes in __pycache__ subdirectory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am using Windows 7 and have both Python 2.7.5 and 3.3.2 installed. My `path` environment variable is set as

```
C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\python27;C:\Python33\Scripts
```

When I import any Python module into another module a `.pyc` file is created. The place where it is created depends on whether Python2 is invoked or Python3 to run it.

- when I double-click the module the `.pyc` file is created in the same directory
- when I am editing via IDLE and then run it then the file is created in the subdirectory.
- If I add `#! Python3` at the top then double-clicking makes the `.pyc` file in the sub-directory.

I understand that the reason for this is because of difference in how Python2 and Python3 have decided to manage the byte-compiled codes.

**I am currently focusing on Python3 and want the files to be created in subdirectory only.**

I tried editing the `path` variable to place Python3 before Python 2 so that Python3 should be invoked instead of Python2. Even after changing it when I double-click the Python script that didn't happen and the byte-compiled code was created in the same directory.

So Python2 was used to run the Python script on double-clicking. What is causing this behaviour and how can I make sure that Python3 is invoked instead of Python2 without uninstalling Python2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python 3 has changed how the bytecode (`.pyc`) files are stored. Python 2 uses the convention of putting them in the same directory, but for Python 3 the developers decided to reduce clutter by putting them all in a separate directory. This also made support for Python implementations other than CPython easier, as each implementation could have its own `.pyc` files in the `__pycache__` directory rather than overwriting those from other implementations.

Comment: So why in my case double-clicking produce compiled files in the same directory unless I am using `#! python3` at the top?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary But [a sub-heading](http://docs.python.org/dev/using/windows.html#from-a-script) of that states that I can use shebang on Windows. Also I had asked that on comp.lang.python and people there told me I can use it.

Comment: @AseemBansal Have you installed [`py launcher`](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher)?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary No I haven't. I have standard Python installation for Python2.7 and Python3.3

Comment: So why does double-clicking invoke Python2 but running through IDLE invoke Python3? I understand that double-clicking a program will caause the OS to look through the PATH variable to find the executable and Python2 is before Python3 but why doesn't that change when I place Python3 before Python2?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Should I install it and why?

Comment: @AseemBansal You can give it a try, I don't have windows system to test these things.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary No I mean what is the advantage due to which you mentioned it?

Comment: The change is in Python 3.2, specifically, not in Python 3 as a whole.